# password-hash works fine but failed to redirect

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a simple login page using **password_hash**.

```
$hp=password_hash( $p, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

My login coding has many `if/else` statements and it works fine until it reached `redirect` part.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require ('mysqli_connect.php');
    if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['username']);
    } 
    else {
        $u = FALSE;
        echo '<p class ="error" >You forgot to enter your username</p>' ;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['psword'])){
        $p= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['psword']);
    }
    else {
        $p= FALSE;
        echo '<p class = "error">You forgot to enter your password</p>';
    }   


    if ($u && $p){      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' ";
        mysqli_store_result($dbcon);
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);

        if (@mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {// to check the username

            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                //de-hashing password
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($p, $row['password']);

                if($hashedPwdCheck == false){
                    echo "wrong password";
                }
                elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true){
                    $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    $_SESSION['user_level'] = (int) $_SESSION['user_level'];            
                    //redirect the user according to user_level
                    if ($_SESSION['user_level'] === 1) {
                        header ("location: admin-page.php");
                        exit();
                    }   
                    elseif ($_SESSION['user_level'] === 2) {
                        header ("location: coordinator-page.php");
                        exit();
                    }
                    else {
                        header ("location: supervisor-homepage.php");
                        exit();
                    }       
                }
            }
            else {
                echo  '<p class="error">There is something wrong. Please try again ';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo '<p class="error">The username you entered is incorrect.<br> Please try again ';
        }                   
    }
    else {
        // If there was a problem.
        echo '<p class="error">Please try again. 2</p>';
    }
}
else {
    echo "There was an error, please try again";
}
?>
```

My `$hashedPwdCheck` returns `true` but as soon as I put 'redirect  according to user level' coding, it gives this output;

[image]

This is my html for the form:

```
 <form action="" method="post">

 <div class = "container" >
 <p align= "center"><label for="username"><b>Username:</label>
 <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" 
 size="30" maxlength="30" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username'];?> 
 "></p>
 <br>

 <p align= "center"><label for="psword1">Password:</b></label>
 <input id="psword" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psword" 
 size="30" maxlength="12" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['psword'])) echo $_POST['psword']; ?>" > 
 <br>


 <p align= "center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" 
 border: 3px   ;></p>

 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: What does actually happen? To which URL are you redirected?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation and formatting often helps identify where things are going wrong. The above code is not easy to follow in places and it's probably a simple error - but your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: I guess redirection is not done at all, is it? It seems as `isset($_POST['submit'])` would fail for some reason, however, the shown form snippet should set a post parameter. Try `var_dump($_POST)` and show the result.

Comment: where you run this script on server or localhost??

Comment: why would you do this ? `$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`??

Comment: @Quasimodo's clone when i click log in, it just stay at the same page. The user supposed to be at "coordinator-page.php".  I try put var_dump($_POST) as you said, and print out this array(0) { }.

Comment: @SomnathMondal i run this on localhost.

Comment: @RamRaider that particular line of coding, this is embarrassing but i got that from a book(seems i'm so desperate). It says that // Start the session, fetch the record and insert the three values in an array
session_start();.. if it brings no good, i will delete it

Comment: as per the comment by @David Blanchard, `$_SESSION` is one of the `superglobal` variables - you can overwrite it but not a good idea

Comment: Updated:  I try to put var_dump($_POST).
It print an empty array when I entered a correct password & username but the array is not empty when I entered a correct username with the wrong password. How can that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought, on a couple of occasions, that I had spotted definitively where the code was breaking but I'm not entirely sure as when I tested your code it redirected ( or tried to ) to the `supervisor` page which is what I'd expect. That said the code is vulnerable to sql injection - perhaps the following might help at this stage.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    try{
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
            if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['psword'] ) ) {
                /* all form processing: start */

                require 'mysqli_connect.php';

                /* 
                    do some rudimentary sanitizing of input data though
                    by using a `prepared statement` you are fairly well
                    protected from malicious user input.
                */
                $args = array(
                    'username'  =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                    'psword'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
                );
                $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );

                /* assign variables from POST data */
                $username = !empty( $_POST['username']  ) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
                $password = !empty( $_POST['psword'] ) ? $_POST['psword'] : false;


                if( !$username )throw new Exception( 'You forgot to enter your username' );
                if( !$password )throw new Exception( 'You forgot to enter your password' );

                $sql='select `password` as `pwd`, `user_level` from `users` where `username`=?';
                $stmt=$dbcon->prepare( $sql );

                /* Abandon ship if the prepared statement failed */
                if( !$stmt )throw new Exception( 'Failed to prepare SQL Query' );

                /* all good, bind placeholder to a variable */
                $stmt->bind_param( 's', $username );


                /* run the query */
                $result = $stmt->execute();

                if( !$result )throw new Exception( 'Query failed' );
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result( $pwd, $userlevel );
                $stmt->fetch();
                $stmt->close();


                /* now confirm that $pwd === $password using password_verify */
                $verified = password_verify( $password, $pwd );

                /* continue logic for success / failure */
                if( !$verified ){

                    throw new Exception( 'Unable to validate username &/or password' );

                } else{
                    switch( $userlevel ){
                        case 1:$page='admin-page.php';break;
                        case 2:$page='coordinator-page.php';break;
                        default:$page='supervisor-homepage.php';break;
                    }
                    /* set SESSION variables */
                    $_SESSION['user_level']=$userlevel;
                    $_SESSION['username']=$username;

                    exit( header( sprintf( 'Location: %s', $page ) ) );
                }


                /* all form processing: end */
                exit();
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Missing POST parameters');
            }
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( sprintf( '<p class="error">There was a problem - %s @ line %d</p>', $e->getMessage(), $e->getLine() ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>login</title>
        <style>
            label{font-weight:bold}
            [type='submit']{float:none;margin:auto}
            p{text-align:center}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            /* values for input fields */
            $username = !empty( $_POST['username'] ) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
            $password = !empty( $_POST['psword'] ) ? $_POST['psword'] : '';
        ?>
        <form method='post'>
            <div class = 'container' >
                <p>
                    <label for='username'>Username:</label>
                    <input id='username' type='text' placeholder='Username' name='username' size='30' maxlength='30' value='<?php echo $username; ?>' />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for='psword1'>Password:</label>
                    <input id='psword' type='password' placeholder='Password' name='psword' size='30' maxlength='12' value='<?php echo $password; ?>' /> 
                <p>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

i'm not really good with php but should there be a space between else and if here?

```
 else if ($_SESSION['user_level'] === 2) {
```

**UPDATE**

Would this work?

```
          if($hashedPwdCheck){

             $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
             $_SESSION['user_level'] = (int) $_SESSION['user_level'];            
                    //redirect the user according to user_level
                    if ($_SESSION['user_level'] === 1) {
                        header ("location: admin-page.php");
                        exit();
                    }   
                    elseif ($_SESSION['user_level'] === 2) {
                        header ("location: coordinator-page.php");
                        exit();
                    }
                    else {
                        header ("location: supervisor-homepage.php");
                        exit();
                    }       

            }
            else {
                echo  '<p class="error">Wrong password';
```

Seems to me that checking for true and false is redundant; this would eliminate the generic 'something went wrong' error and help you troubleshoot.

Comment: `else if` has special key words in many languages. In PHP it's `elseif` as an alias for the long form. Other languages use e.g. `elif`

Comment: Yeah, there shouldn't be a space. I fix it but it doesn't change anything. Thank you btw

Comment: `elseif` is valid in PHP

Comment: i've updated my answer, just trying to be helpful, OP said there was a typo so don't kill me

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work... I guess there's must be something silly that I don't noticed. Going to keep looking

Comment: Even it is not a technically correct answer, I like to see when beginners try to help beginners. It actually is an attempt to give a well formed answer on SO, so I disagree downvotes. We can improve things by giving hints in comments on answers with a wrong idea as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll attempt to answer your initial question. Looking over your code really quick, I noticed this line:

```
$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

It looks to me like you're trying to replace the $_SESSION Superglobal with the result of an SQL query. I don't think this is the right way to go.

Try this instead:

```
$_SESSION["user"] = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Then reference the "user_level" column in your associative array by using

```
$_SESSION["user"]["user_level"]
```

For the 2nd part of this, I'll offer a bit of advice. 
***Don't use mysqli. It's deprecated and insecure.*** ***<--- This is wrong! I'm dumb don't pay attention to that!***

Mysqli is fine.. But PDO is more flexible (depending on what you're doing).. I was thinking of the one before mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

But PDO is still awesome and worth learning about. 
Really great tutorial here --> https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Thanks to the comments below for pointing out my nonsense.

Comment: `mysqli` is not deprecated nor insecure if used correctly. It is the `mysql` api that has been deprecated and is less secure as it does not support prepared statements

Comment: `mysqli` is even more secure than `PDO` while PDO is just more flexible.